# Not getting data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I am executing this code:

```
var element=null;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: "C:\Users\myDir\Desktop\Project\jsonfile.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
        element=data;
        }
    });
```

JSON structure:

```
{
   "info":[
      {
         "a1": "Ram",
         "b1": "P123"
      },
      {
         "a1": "ROM",
         "b1": "P245"
      }
     ]
}
```

but i am getting nothing in variable

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: nothing in varaible ?? is there any error.. try with `alert(element.info[0].a1)` inside succes function and check if you are getting the alert

Comment: I tried simple alert("hi"); after element=data;... its also not working

Comment: Try console.log(data); in your ajax success function and check your browser console whether yor are getting any data

Comment: It is not at all going inside Ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Check for any error in the ajax using

```
var element=null;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: "jsonfile.json",//Edited
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
        element=data;
        }
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this code.It is showing 404 Not Found error.How to rectify this problem??

Comment: So your url: "C:\Users\myDir\Desktop\Project\jsonfile.json", is not correct.Change it to url: "jsonfile.json".See the edit in the answer

Comment: If I give url like "C:\Users\myDir\Desktop\Project\jsonfile.json", the error is No Transport.If I give this "jsonfile.json", the error is Not Found.

Comment: Are you sure jsonfile.json is the file. is it jsonfile.php.I am doubtfull about the file extension.Check do you have a file named jsonfile.json.The error shows that there is no such file

Comment: Yes.I have checked.This is my url: "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Training\mapInput.json"

Answer (score -1):

may be the permission issue for the file. insert the json file with all your other code files and give relative path in the url

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: "jsonfile.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
        element=data;
        }
    });
```

//location of json file is same as the file making ajax call